# How to get my exterior door to close when the interior door is also shut? Air pressure problem.

Tags: repair, doors

We have a new porch and new composite front door which fits well and shuts without difficulty when the inner door is open. If the inner door is shut, the outer door will not close without great difficulty and a lot of pulling and banging. This is putting a strain on the handle and so we have resorted to having to leave the inner door open to be able to leave the house. The inner door is not a particularly air tight. I removed the draught proof tape on the inner door, to see if an increased gap would help but no improvement. I do not want to put a hole in my new exterior door. Can anyone suggest anything that might help? We are planning to replace the inner door soon as the existing inner door is damaged, so if there's anything we might be able to do with this door please could you let me know? Any helpful suggestions appreciated

Comment: Have you tried closing the outer door very slowly to give the air pressure buildup time to escape?

Comment: You're going to need a relief vent somewhere. It could be to the outside, or in the inner door. You can determine how large it needs to be by experimenting with how large a gap one needs to hold with the inner door in order for the outer door to operate reasonably. An outside vent could likely be a fair bit smaller.

Comment: Do you have the same difficulty entering the house;  closing the inner door when the outer door is already closed?

Comment: Try closing the door very slowly: if the issue still happens then it's not air pressure at the root cause.

Comment: Relief vent might also go into porch ceiling. Depending on construction, porch roofs are not always air-tight, which is what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Before concentrating on an air pressure solution, I would eliminate two other possibilities:

1. The handles on the inner and outer doors are interfering very slightly with each other.  Check the height of each handle above the sill, and the spacing between the two doors when closed;
2. The act of closing the inner door distorts the door frame slightly, shifting the outer door from the "fits well" category to the "fits with great difficulty" category...